# Unzip in c# SSIS script task using Icsharpcode library

Tags: c#, ssis

I need to programatically unzip a zip file in c# in an SSIS Script task. I know there is a free library called Icsharpcode. Has anyone done this. If so any hints or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a script task that uses a standaard microsoft library:
[link Script Task](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/01/unzip-files-with-ssis.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've used the CozyRoc tools for unzipping files as well as command line executions.  I would certainly be interested in learning how things go if you successfully implement the code.